# Share in facebook without open the confirmation dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

Hy friends,

I want to add a facebook share buttom on my website, but with a few custom modifications. When the user clicks on the share button, don't show the dialog window, like one in the [image](http://postimage.org/image/xyczwla2h/)

I want that after click fill in backround the $image, $title, $url, $summary, the text in the "Write something..." sections. Instead of Share: **On your own Wall** thing to share on my website's facebook wall( ex. www.facebook.com/mywebsite). Do all this in background without open that confitmation dialog window.

Can anyone give me a tip, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at open graph concepts: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/

but have in mind, that the user acceptance/experience is really important. you should never mislead your user. so read and always have in mind the two following links:

- [Open Graph Checklist](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/submission-process/opengraph/guidelines/)
- [Facebook Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/policy_checklist/english/)

Comment: the pre-fill of a custom user message isn't allowed at all.